# Select data between date ranges from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Let suppose I have two table

1. Taxes
2. Products

I want to select sum of product values multiplied by their respective VAT value in taxes table as a percentage where the date of the product is less than date of tax and `mDate` is less than product date, grouped by VAT or `ttid`

For example

```
        Taxes                                          products

 ttid     date    value  mDate                    Vat    value    date
  0     02-06-11    20    03-07-11                0       15    01-07-11
  1     03-07-11    10    03-08-11                0       15    01-07-11
  0     03-07-11    14    03-08-11                0       15    02-08-11
  1     03-08-11    15    03-09-11                1       10    04-07-11
                                                  1       10    06-08-11
                                                  1       10    08-09-11  --this will not include
```

So my result will look like this.

```
TTId   Value
0       3+3+2.1=8.1
1       1.5+1=2.5
```

The query I have written so far.

```
select   sum
          ( 
            (cast(t.Value as float)
             *
            (cast(x.value as float)/100)
          )
    as 'Vat'
   ,x.ttid
 from prducts t 
,taxes x where x.ttid=t.vat  and  x.mDate>t.date and x.date<=t.date
group by x.ttid
```

Will somebody help me?

Comment: Assuming these talks of VAT and tax mean that one or more of these amounts is currency, please don't use float - use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) with a suitable scale and precision.

Comment: Can you check your SUM calculation please. You have + followed by *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(Vat)'Vat',itemvat,sum(productvalue)'ProductValue' from
(
SELECT
 t.vat,
t.value,
   isnull(t.value *
     (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM #TMP x where x.ttid=t.vat  and 
 convert(varchar,cast(x.effectiveDate as datetime),3)>convert(varchar,cast(t.date as datetime),3)
and convert(varchar,cast(x.mDate as datetime),3)<=convert(varchar,cast(t.date as datetime),3)

)/100,'5') 
as 'Vat'
FROM products t  
) 
as t where Vat<>'5' group by itemvat
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

As stated in the comments you've got `+` followed by `*`

In the Tax table `date` always has a value less than `mdate`. Your `WHERE` test has `x.date>t.datee and x.mDate<=t.date` which implies that `x.date` is greater than `x.mDate`. This will always be false

You've spelt `t.date` with an extra e in the `WHERE` clause

You misspelled `products` as the name of the table.

In addition, using `t` as the alias for `products` and `x` as the alias for `tax` is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   SUM( t.Value *
     ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 value FROM taxes x where x.ttid=t.vat and t.date BETWEEN x.date AND x.mDate order by t.datee), 100)/100) as 'Vat'
FROM prducts t
```

Comment: I am getting error!Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery